# Finding the coefficient of expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Question:

Find the coefficient of $x^{11}$ in the expansion of:$$(1+x^2)^4(1+x^3)^7(1+x^4)^{12}$$

The traditional way of doing this, as far as I know, is to first find the coefficient of each term that has $x^{11}$, and then sum it. However, with three individual terms in multiplication, this would be a very tedious job. Is there a shorter way to approach such problems?

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the coefficient by hand is somewhat cumbersome. Here is a notation which helps to make it better manageable. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> We obtain by successively applying the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)*
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^{11}]&(1+x^2)^4(1+x^3)^7(1+x^4)^{12}\\
> &=[x^{11}]\sum_{j=0}^{12}\binom{12}{j}x^{4j}(1+x^2)^4(1+x^3)^7\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{2}\binom{12}{j}[x^{11-4j}](1+x^2)^4(1+x^3)^7\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{2}\binom{12}{j}[x^{11-4j}]\sum_{k=0}^7\binom{7}{k}x^{3k}(1+x^2)^4\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{2}\sum_{k=0}^3\binom{12}{j}\binom{7}{k}[x^{11-4j-3k}](1+x^2)^4\qquad\qquad\quad 4j+3k\leq 11\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{2}\sum_{k=0}^3\binom{12}{j}\binom{7}{k}[x^{11-4j-3k}]
> \sum_{l=0}^{4}\binom{4}{l}x^{2l}\qquad\qquad 4j+3k\leq 11\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{2}\sum_{k=0}^3\sum_{l=0}^{4}
> \binom{12}{j}\binom{7}{k}\binom{4}{l}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad 4j+3k+2l= 11\tag{6}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In  (1) we start expanding the binomial with the greatest power $x^4$ which keeps the number of summands small as we will see in the next step.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[x^{m-n}]=[x^m]x^n$. Note that since the power of $x$ is non negative, the upper limit of the index $j$ is now $2$.
- In (3) we expand the binomial $(1+x^3)^7$.
- In (4) we do a similar job as in (2) and keep in mind, that  the power of $x$ is non-negative by stating $4j+3k\leq 11$.
- In (5) we expand the last binomial
- In (6) we apply the coefficient of operator the last time and obtain a summation formula for the coefficient of $x^{11}$.

> The final step is to do some bookkeeping and look according to (6) for all triples $(j,k,l)$ with
>
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{matrix}
> 0\leq j \leq 2\\
> 0\leq k \leq 3\\
>  0\leq l \leq 4\\
> \end{matrix}
> \qquad\quad\text{and}\quad\qquad 4j+3k+2l= 11
> \end{align*}
>
> We find
>   \begin{array}{rrrrr}
>   j&k&l&\binom{12}{j}\binom{7}{k}\binom{4}{l}&\sum\\
> \hline
>   2&1&0&462&462\\
>   1&1&2&504&966\\
>   0&1&4&7&973\\
>   0&3&1&140&\color{blue}{1113}\\
>   \end{array}
>
> resulting finally in
>
> \begin{align*}
> [x^{11}](1+x^2)^4(1+x^3)^7(1+x^4)^{12}=1113
> \end{align*}
>
> in accordance with the result of *[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E4%281%2Bx%5E3%29%5E7%281%2Bx%5E4%29%5E12%20taylor%20expansion)*.

Comment: I got it until the last step. How do we find the values of j, k, l that satisfy the equation?

Comment: @Gummybears: We know the range of $j,k,l$ and start with the greatest value for $j$, which is $j=2$. Since we want to find triples with $4j+3k+2l=11$ and $4j=4\cdot 2=8$ we see that $k=1$ and $l=0$ is a valid triple. Then we successively decrement $k$ and $l$ by one and add $l$, resp. $k$ and $l$ accordingly to always have $4j+3k+2l=11$.

Comment: So essentially it's trial and error? No better method?

Comment: @Gummybears:  No, no, it's  not trial and method. Since we systematically find the maximum $j,k,l$ and then we do it iteratively by decrementing the indices by one. But, you're right, this also becomes soon cumbersome, if the complexity grows. In such situations I typically write some code snippets, to find the triples systematically and to check the calculations. Regards,

Comment: I was looking for a method that would serve me during an examination. :)

Comment: @Gummybears: I see, sorry! :-) Nevertheless, keep this technique in mind, since it's really helpful for small tasks containing two, three binomials. ... and Wolfram Alpha is not always available ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your equation, I feel like the only way you can get $x^{11}$ is $(x^2)^4 * x^3 *constant$ or $(x^2)^2 * x^3 * x^4$ or $x^2 * (x^3)^2 * constant$ or $constant * x^3 * (x^4)^2$. Then you can use formula for binomial expansion to calculate the coefficients for each term. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the coefficient of whichever term you wish by using a [Taylor expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E4%281%2Bx%5E3%29%5E7%281%2Bx%5E4%29%5E12%20taylor%20expansion). Indeed, the binomial series is just the [Maclaurin series for $(1 + x)^n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) (i.e. the Taylor expansion about $x = 0$).

Doing so you'll find that the coefficient of $x^{11}$ is $1113$.